# Visual Studio 2013/2012 hangs when clicking Add View dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

After the Update 4 and Web Tools 2013.1, Visual Studio 2012 hangs when I click Add View dialog. 
The project contains a few thousand of classes, so I tried to remove them temporarily and clicked Add View again - the Add View dialog now opened in a few seconds. Seems that VS doing something in the background that takes too much time. The same issue occurs on Visual Studio 2013 as well.